# Cannot access existing worksheet with xlsxwriter using arcpy tool

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy

I want to populate an existing Excel sheet with values from an ArcGIS feature class. I have made a tool using arcpy and xlsxwriter. I use shutil to copy the template excel in the new location and this is how I create the workbook and the worksheet object:

```
shutil.copy2(template_xl,out_file)
wb=xlsxwriter.Workbook(out_file)
arcpy.AddMessage(type(wb))
ws=wb.get_worksheet_by_name("POS")
arcpy.AddMessage(type(ws))
ws.write(4,0,"test")
```

And I get the messages:

```
<class 'xlsxwriter.workbook.Workbook'>
<type 'NoneType'>
Failed script POSCreator...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  ----, line 62, in <module>
    ws.write(4,0,"test")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'
```

If I use:

```
ws=wb.worksheets()[0]
```

Then I get the message *list out of index*, although I need the first (and only) sheet in the excel file.
The variables *out_file* and *template_xl* are valid paths.

Answer (score 1):

I have finally figured out that you can't do this with xlsxwriter. With this module I can only build from scratch the workbook.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18002133/xlsxwriter-is-there-a-way-to-open-an-existing-worksheet-in-my-workbook

Comment: To read/update Excel files with Python, use openpyxl: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/